# No core dump file generated after segmentation fault in macOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, macos-big-sur, coredump

I recently bought the new M1 chip Macbook Pro, running MacOS Big Sur, but no core files are generated after the process received SIGSEGV or segmentation fault.

My old Macbook running MacOS Sierra, generates the core file in /cores directory, and the problem is only with the new MacOS Big Sur.

Did all of the following :

```
# ulimit -c unlimited
# sudo chmod 1777 /cores  (also tried chmod 1775).

# sysctl -a | grep core
kern.corefile: /cores/core.%P
kern.coredump: 1
kern.sugid_coredump: 0
```

Also tried many other things mentioned in other forums.
None of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround:-
If we run the Terminal application under Rosetta 2, we get the core dumps then.

Just do a get info on the Terminal app, and check the box - "open using Rosetta"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zyed9.png)